# Integrating command-line tool with Emacs

Tags: emacs, command-line

I have a Java command-line tool which I'd like to use from inside Emacs.
The tool is interactive, meaning it asks the user for input.
I'm interested in running it from Emacs, and controlling it using the minibuffer.

Running a shell is bad UI, as there are no Emacs abilities like history.

Is there an existing, supported way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `comint` mechanism is the general method.

The very simplest method is:
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `comint-run` <kbd>RET</kbd> `<name of tool>` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Your best reference is very likely to be Mickey's write-up at his [Mastering Emacs](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2013/07/31/comint-writing-command-interpreter/) site. (As he says, comint is "woefully underdocumented" in Emacs' own manuals.)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a persisent history with emacs' shell: 
http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Shell#Shared_and_persistent_history

Try that:

```
 (add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'my-shell-mode-hook)
 (defun my-shell-mode-hook ()
  (setq comint-input-ring-file-name "~/.zsh_history")  ;; or bash_history
  (comint-read-input-ring t))
```